# Raleigh Motus Tour 2018 - Chain electric bike replacement

Tags: chain, electric-bike

I have to replace the chain of my Raleigh Motus Tour 2018.

Do anyone knows the specify chain I have to buy?

Because it is a electric bike I am almost sure that I should buy the KMC "e9 EPT for e-Bike" or the "e9 Silver for e-Bike", which has 136 links.

https://www.kmcchain.eu/chain-e_bike-multispeed-9_speed

Edit 1:

My bike has a Bosch engine (Active Line) as well and it is 46 cm frame size.

[image: Raleigh Motus Tour Step Through Derailleur Electric Bike]

Edit 2:

After going to a bike store where I could find one like mine I could take the picture of the chain and get the model.

It is a KMC X9, but it has 126 links. The ones I found on the internet has only 114 links. It is not possible to find a KMC X9 with 126 links.

Another important info is the fact KMC chains has 6.6 mm of pin length. Shimano and others brands has 6.5 mm. After that, I am questioning myself if the guy who measured the chain knew it and made a proper diagnostic when doing the M check on my bike.

Anyways, I still seeking for the right answer. In case the chain is not good, should I buy a KMC e9 EPT and remove some links as it has 136?

Comment: I've found a stock image of your bike - if this is wrong, please revert the edit.   It does appear to have a relatively long chainstay, and an unusual chainring setup.

Comment: If the bike requires a chain longer than the stock replacement the usual thing to do would be to buy two chains and splice a bit of one onto the other.  Save the remainder for the next chain or if you need to replace a damaged section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to buy a KMC e9 EPT (it has 136 links of 6.6 mm) and remove 10 links.

Answer (score 3):

Any 9 speed chain will do, of those two, one claims anti rust, the other not. For a well maintained bike, it makes no difference (except maybe cosmetics).

If the bike has a hub motor it makes no difference as no power is transmitted though the chain.  If the drive has a mid-drive motor, power is transmitted though the chain, but there is some debate if there is debate over if the label 'e-chain' is more than marketing.

An elite rider can output well over 1000W vs 200-300W for a ebike, so strength of the chain to handle high load is not the issue, any bike chain can handle the power of an E-Bike motor. In terms of torque, similar argument - torque of a 100kg rider standing on cranks is 175Nm, and an elite rider can probably double that momentarily, while most eBike motors produce half of that.

Wear is likely impacted as you ride further and mostly importantly, faster on an ebike. Chains wear out, that is a given. How much faster a 'normal' chain wears out over an ebike chain, and cost and inconvenience of replacement,  is the reason to go an ebike specific chain.

Personally I would not pay a premium for an Ebike specific chain.

Comment: It has to be a specific one. I went to Halfords (a bicycle store in the UK) and they tried 2 Shimano chains, but it was short.

Comment: Chains can be bought in different lengths, but its got little to do with E-Bike compatibility (Except some ebikes require longer chains than most bikes)

Comment: @AlexandreRibeiro  Regular (non-motorized) tandems and recumbents may have chains with around 200 links. Chains can easily be shortened or lengthened as every combination of chainstay length and cogs sizes requires its own number of links. What matters most for a chain is compatibility with the rest of the drivetrain (how many rear gears are there), and then it is its wearing qualities (how long it will work until becoming too worn out).

Comment: @AlexandreRibeiro To be precise: There are three things that matter for a chain: 1) Length (must be adjusted anyways, you just need to buy at least as many links as you need), 2) width (mostly important for chain-shift bikes, usually irrelevant with single speed or IGH), and 3) flexibility (again, mostly important for chain-shifts, irrelevant for single speed or IGH). Force and power are not among these, any chain has ample margin for both. You can hang half a ton on a bike chain, and expect it to hold the weight.